# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while installing maven project

Tags: java, maven, exception, plugins

I'm trying to install maven project but facing an

> exception: Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test
>   (default-test)

There are test failures.

When I looked at the .dump file I see this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:513)

at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class java/lang/UnknownError could not be instrumented.

org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_c13123e.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:140)

org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_c13123e.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:101)

    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_c13123e.PreMain.createRuntime(PreMain.java:55)

    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_c13123e.PreMain.premain(PreMain.java:47)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: $jacocoAccess

    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1999)

org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_c13123e.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:138)

*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at  line: 422
```

I'm pretty sure there is no any problems in the code as it works well on other computers. Skipping tests is not an option because it is an integration-tests module

Comment: I saw similar questions and nevertheless I opened this topic because  existing answers didn't solve my problem

Comment: Most likely an incompatibility between jacoco version and the JDK version that's running your maven project.  Try to google on 'NoSuchFieldException: $jacocoAccess' and you'll find a few useful hits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer below helped. For me it was a problem between Jacoco version and my JDK.

There are two options to solve this:

1. Make sure that there is an appropriate version for your JDK and upgrade jacoco
2. Use an older JDK

Comment: Upgrading Jacoco is what resolved the issue for me after upgrading to Java 11

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to the given answer. My issue was due to the fact that I was using Java 14. JaCoCo needed an older version. So I downloaded and installed JDK 1.8.0. Now in IntelliJ:

Go to `project structure` (top right)

[image]

Click on `Project` under `Project Settings`

[image]

Then select JDK 1.8

[image]

Comment: Also -- if this doesn't help and you are using Gradle (too?) -- make sure the (Settings>Build>Tools>)Gradle page shows the "Gradle JVM" setting is also 1.8 (same as the project SDK above)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gradle and failing `test with coverage`
try changing Gradle JVM
[image]

then it worked for me